# Azure DevOps: Use pipelines to deploy BAR files to IBM Integration Bus

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ibm-integration-bus

The goal I'm trying to accomplish is migrating out of CVS to using Azure Repos. Currently BAR deployments are sent through CVS repos and then deployed to IBM Integration Bus. I would like to accomplish this same process through Azure DevOps.

I know this extension exists: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.ibm-integration-bus&ssr=false#overview

However there is limited documentation available. I'm curious to know if anyone has had success using the above extension?

If not through the extension is there another solution available?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that extension myself.

The tasks involved in setting up a build and deploy pipeline are not difficult, so you should be able to roll your own.

See [mqsicreatebar](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=commands-mqsicreatebar-command) and [mqsipackagebar](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=commands-mqsipackagebar-command) for how to build the BAR files.
See [mqsideploy](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=commands-mqsideploy-command) for details of how to deploy the BAR files.

The rest will depend very much on your chosen source code control system and build orchestration technology.